# How to Convert Double Byte String to Single Byte String?

Tags: c#, textbox

I am a newbie at C#.
I have a `Textbox` and it is allowed to accept `double_byte` string and it is used to input/show **Date Value**.
Now I am having a problem and I don't know how to solve this.I googled about it,and can't find any solution for it.
When I wrote `Double_Byte` Characters( **２０１２／１２／３１**) ,I want to change this value to (**2012/12/31**) at `Leave_Event` of TextBox or `Text_Changed` Event of this TextBox. So, How can I solve the problem.
**Edit**->My Solution is Window Application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by " is allowed to accept double_byte string " ?

Comment: to store that value in database , what datatype you have used at backend[database]?

Comment: I means User can Type Double_Byte Character in the Textbox.

Comment: you are using ASP .NET or its windows app?

Comment: you might try to do something similar to this:

var bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.ASCII, sourceString);

string ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

Comment: The example you posted *looks* like a valid date, but actually isn't.  The Unicode code-points you used (0xFF12, 0xFF10, 0xFF11, 0xFF12, 0xFF0F, ...) may *look* like the ASCII numbers for the date, but they are actually full-width glyphs for digits and various ASCII characters.  You need to convert them to ASCII before you can use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all of your answers and interests.
I searched a solution for this and not found any answer .Finally ,I got a nice answer from my colleague.
Therefore, I share the answer of this problem.

1. Add Reference Microsoft.VisualBasic
2. write code like this(test like [sa_ddam213's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15332144/507860))-

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string inputText = textBox1.Text;
      string singleByteString =  Strings.StrConv(inputText, VbStrConv.Narrow, 0);

      textBox2.Text = singleByteString;
      textBox3.Text = inputText;
}
```

Comment: +1, Another hidden gem in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace :)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `Encoding.Default` to convert the `double_byte` string to a `single_byte` string

```
 string singleByteString = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputText));
```

Tests:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string inputText = textBox1.Text;
        string singleByteString = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputText));

        textBox2.Text = singleByteString;
        textBox3.Text = inputText;
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It still give ２０１２／１２／３１.I tested simple window application like you mentioned above.

Comment: try `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputText))`

Comment: `?Q?O?P?Q?^?P?Q?^?R?P` is the result of `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputText))`

Comment: Thank you, I added a solution.

Answer (score -1):

When you send your text box value in database , parse it to Date.

Make sure that you are storing that text box'x value in database as DateTime datatype.

parsing can be done as follows>

```
double d = double.Parse(txtDate.text);
DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
```

Or simplest way use>>

```
DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: With the Unicode strings the OP is dealing with, this will fail.

Comment: DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text); will not fail. I have tried it in many windows apps.

Comment: Really?  Have you tried it on the Unicode string the OP just posted, which uses code-points that are way outside the standard ASCII range?  It fails.  It doesn't know that Unicode code-point FF10 is a '0' for instance.  Unless there's something funky with your localization settings?