# PHP Convert Double Byte String to Single Byte String?

Tags: php, double-byte

I have a string with double byte, now I want convert to 1 byte.

Example:

$input = "**２０１２／１２／３１**";

I want to output: **2012/12/31**

For C#: [How to Convert Double Byte String to Single Byte String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331818/how-to-convert-double-byte-string-to-single-byte-string)

---

Found the anwser from:

[how to transform japanese english character to normal english character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776998/how-to-transform-japanese-english-character-to-normal-english-character)

However mb_convert_kana in my pc not run

```
mb_convert_kana("２０１２／１２／３１", "rnaskhc");
```

Comment: If you know encoding of original string you may use `iconv` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the function [`mb_convert_kana`](http://php.net/mb_convert_kana), most likely with the mode `as` (zen-kaku alphanumerics and spaces to han-kaku). "Double byte" is the wrong term, those are *full-width* characters.

Comment: This is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776998/how-to-transform-japanese-english-character-to-normal-english-character

Thank you for your keyword