# Convert double byte (full width) to single byte character string (half width) Japanese katakana

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert Full-width katakana to Half-width katakana

I tried to use

```
string userInput = "ラーメン";    
result = userInput.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC)
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149897/12744547

Expected result: "ﾗｰﾒﾝ"

Actual result: "ラーメン" same as input

it only works on numbers letters and symbols not in actual katakana/Japanese Character.

Comment: I found this sample on how to convert from half-width to full-width and its working fine for me but I don't know how to reverse this method reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237910/12744547

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331818/how-to-convert-double-byte-string-to-single-byte-string

Comment: i tried but it returns "???"